# Mac ssh: illegal option -- J

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal, proxy

I'm trying to connect with ssh and need to use -J.
It works fine on Ubuntu but on mac it returns - `illegal option -- J`

Comment: Hello google for "manual ssh mac" and "manual ssh ubuntu" - look for differences

Answer (score 0):

Connected with this command

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p Jumphost" FooServer
```

Find out in this article https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-ssh-proxycommand-passing-through-one-host-gateway-server/